# ARKit: Are renderer(didAdd: ) and renderer(nodeFor: ) exclusive

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Relying completely on `ARKit` automatic plane detection is something I don't want to do since it takes time to detect surfaces and then real life surfaces should be textured enough, hence I need to think of something to give an option where if I want I should be able to add anchors at my will with a tap of a button.

Here is where `renderer(nodeFor: )` comes in handy. Just add an anchor at the tap of a button, using `hitTest` to ascertain the position of the anchor and then add nodes using `nodeFor:` method.

However, in other cases when I don't want to manually tap buttons, `renderer(didAdd: )` should work. I have made a sharedObject through which I can ascertain whether plane detection needs to be "**automated**" or "**manual**". In case it's automated `planeDetection` would be set as `.horizontal` whereas in case it is manual, `planeDetection` would be set as `[]`.

The issue is on testing it appears that either one of the two methods under delegate would work. ***Is there a way that I can achieve what I desire?*** Having a switch using which I can toggle whether I want automated plane detection or I want to add anchors and then planes. I would love to have both option.

Is it possible to use two different delegates to achieve it, just a thought...in that case how would it work. Pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `renderer(didAdd: )` and `renderer(nodeFor: )` are exclusive. As per the docs, if we want to implement our own method for adding node in the scene, we can go ahead and use `renderer(nodeFor: )`, or we can **instead** choose ARKit to do the same for us using `renderer(didAdd: )`.

The way to manage both cases, viz. adding nodes manually while `planeDetection = []`; automatically adding nodes when `planeDetection = .horizontal` can be achieved by using `renderer(nodeFor: )` method itself. There is no need of `renderer(didAdd: )`.

Within `renderer(nodeFor: )` in case of planeDetection = .horizontal, anchor can be casted as `ARPlaneAnchor` whose *center* and *extent* can be used to update the added node.

Such as:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
        let node = SCNNode()
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x),
                             height: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z))

        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.name = "anchorPlane"
        planeNode.simdPosition = float3(planeAnchor.center.x, 0, planeAnchor.center.z)
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        return node
```

At the same time, another condition can be imposed for `planeDetection = []`, when anchor can't be casted as `ARPlaneAnchor`, and geometry underlying the node can be given size as desired.

```
    } else {
        let node = SCNNode()
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: 0.5, height: 0.5)
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        node.addChildNode(node)
        return node
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is not other/ better answer, this would be accepted as the answer.